# Sending Array of Object from SendMessage

Tags: mfc, sendmessage

I have an application which utilises two version of projects one is MFC based and other is win32 based project. For communicating between these two projects I am using SendMessage() with only one input in LPARAM. Is there any way I can send multiple input or array of inputs/object in LPARAM  of SendMessage().
I will write the code if required

Comment: Another option is to use shared memory to send data between applications : http://www.naughter.com/memmap.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [WM_COPYDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx). The documentation also contains a sample.